# dotenv not reading variables inside .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm trying to use `dotenv` to load the following .env file:

```
PORT=4000
BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}/
```

```js
require('dotenv').config('.env')
```

For some reasons, `dotenv` does not resolve `${PORT}` to `4000`, instead it just returns a plain string like this:

```js
{
  parsed: {
    PORT: '4000',
    BASE_URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:$PORT/',
  }
}
```

How can I make `dotenv` read variables inside `.env` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotenv-expand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand) because [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) doesn't support variable substitution using `${}` syntax.

to use `dotenv-expand` install

```bash
npm install dotenv-expand
```

add require dotenvExpand keep the same `.env` file with `${}` syntax

```js
var dotenv = require("dotenv");
var dotenvExpand = require("dotenv-expand");

var result = dotenv.config();
dotenvExpand.expand(result);

console.log(result.parsed);
```

The output will return like:

```json
{
  PORT: '4000',
  BASE_URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/'
}
```

Output:

[image: output of env substitution]

Comment: In newer versions it will not work.
Try this instead:
`var result = dotenv.config({processEnv: {}});
dotenvExpand.expand(result);`

Answer (score 0):

try to access to your variable with `process.env`
for exemple `process.env.PORT`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).